# Implementing custom tab bar in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, user-interface

Any tips on how to implement something like this in react native

this middle button should have something like a gap around it

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3EfG.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the gap, I would use a .png in a custom component.

Answer (score 0):

Never done it before, but looks this guy solved it https://github.com/hoaphantn7604/react-native-curved-bottom-bar. Seems they are using **react-native-svg** to do the magic